# EaselJS (sprite animation won't play during diagonal direction)

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, easeljs

I'm having an issue where a game sprite animation doesn't play during diagonal movement, it just gets stuck on the first frame of the diagonal animation. If anyone knows what's up I would be very grateful.

```
function init() {

    'use strict';

    var menuSelected = false;

    var shape = new createjs.Shape();
    var g = shape.graphics;
    shape.graphics.beginFill("#ffffff").drawRect(100, 300, 450, 100, 25);

    var $container, canvas, stage, canvasW, canvasH,
        manifest, totalLoaded, queue,
        map1, mapTiles, game, mapWidth, mapHeight, tileSheet, tiles, board,
        player, playerSheet, firstKey,
        keysPressed = {
            38: 0,
            40: 0,
            37: 0,
            39: 0
        };

    $container = document.getElementById("container");
    canvasW = 640;
    canvasH = 416;

    map1 = [
        [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ];
    mapTiles = {};

    function buildMap(map) {

        var row, col, tileClone, tileIndex, defineTile;

        if (!board) {
            board = new createjs.Container();
            board.x = 0;
            board.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(board);
        }

        mapWidth = map[0].length;
        mapHeight = map.length;

        defineTile = {
            walkable: function (row, col) {
                if (map[row][col] === 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };

        tileIndex = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++) {
                tileClone = tiles.clone();
                tileClone.name = "t_" + row + "_" + col;
                tileClone.gotoAndStop(map[row][col]);
                tileClone.x = col * tileSheet._frameWidth;
                tileClone.y = row * tileSheet._frameHeight;
                mapTiles["t_" + row + "_" + col] = {
                    index: tileIndex,
                    walkable: defineTile.walkable(row, col)
                };
                tileIndex++;
                board.addChild(tileClone);
            }
        }

    }

    function addPlayer(x, y) { 
        player.x = x * tileSheet._frameWidth + (tileSheet._frameWidth / 2);
        player.y = y * tileSheet._frameHeight + (tileSheet._frameHeight / 2);
        player.speed = 6;
        player.height = 96;
        player.width = 96;
        player.gotoAndStop("standDown");
        board.addChild(player);
    }

    function moveChar(char, dirx, diry) {       
        if (dirx === 0) {
             char.y += diry * char.speed;
           }
        if (diry === 0) {
               char.x += dirx * char.speed;
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        keysPressed[e.keyCode] = 1;
        if (!firstKey) { firstKey = e.keyCode; }
    });

    document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        if (keysPressed[88] === 1) {
            menuSelected = !(menuSelected); 
        }

        keysPressed[e.keyCode] = 0;
        if (firstKey === e.keyCode) { firstKey = null; }
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkDown") { player.gotoAndStop("standDown");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkRight") { player.gotoAndStop("standRight");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkUp") { player.gotoAndStop("standUp");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkLeft") { player.gotoAndStop("standLeft");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkDiagUpRight") { player.gotoAndStop("standDiagUpRight");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkDiagUpLeft") { player.gotoAndStop("standDiagUpLeft");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkDiagDownRight") { player.gotoAndStop("standDiagDownRight");}
        if (player.currentAnimation == "walkDiagDownLeft") { player.gotoAndStop("standDiagDownLeft");}
    });

    function detectKeys() {
        if (keysPressed[38] === 1) {    
            if (player.currentAnimation !== "walkUp") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkUp"); }
            moveChar(player, 0, -1);
        }
        if (keysPressed[40] === 1) {   
            if (player.currentAnimation !== "walkDown") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkDown"); }
            moveChar(player, 0, 1);
        }
        if (keysPressed[37] === 1) { 
            if (player.currentAnimation !== "walkLeft") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkLeft"); }
            moveChar(player, -1, 0);
        }
        if (keysPressed[39] === 1) {    
            if (player.currentAnimation !== "walkRight") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkRight"); }
            moveChar(player, 1, 0);
        }

        // diagonal movement
       if (keysPressed[38] === 1 && keysPressed[37] === 1) {
            player.gotoAndPlay("walkDiagUpLeft");
        }
        if (keysPressed[38] === 1 && keysPressed[39] === 1) {
            player.gotoAndPlay("walkDiagUpRight");
        }
        if (keysPressed[40] === 1 && keysPressed[37] === 1) {
            player.gotoAndPlay("walkDiagDownLeft");
        }
        if (keysPressed[40] === 1 && keysPressed[39] === 1) {
            player.gotoAndPlay("walkDiagDownRight");
        }  
    }

    function handleTick() {
        detectKeys();
        if (menuSelected === true) {
            stage.addChild(shape);
        }
        if (menuSelected === false) {
            stage.removeChild(shape);
        }
        stage.update();
    }

    function gameInit() {
        manifest = [
            {src: "img/tileset.png", id: "tiles"},
            {src: "img/swordsman-spritesheet.png", id: "player"}
        ];
        totalLoaded = 0;

        function handleLoadComplete(event) {
            totalLoaded++;
            if (totalLoaded < manifest.length) {
                console.log(totalLoaded + "/" + manifest.length + " loaded");
            }
        }

        function handleFileLoad(event) {
            var img, audio;
            if (event.item.type === "image") {
                img = new Image();
                img.src = event.item.src;
                img.onload = handleLoadComplete;
            } else if (event.item.type === "sound") {
                audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = event.item.src;
                audio.onload = handleLoadComplete;
            }
        }

        function handleComplete(event) {
            buildMap(map1);
            addPlayer(3, 4, 0);
        }

        queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        queue.installPlugin(createjs.SoundJS);
        queue.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
        queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
        queue.loadManifest(manifest);

        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        stage.enableMouseOver(30);
        createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
        createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);

        tileSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
            images: ["img/tileset.png"],
            frames: {
                height: 32,
                width: 32,
                regX: 0,
                regY: 0,
                count: 3
            }
        });

        tiles = new createjs.Sprite(tileSheet);

        playerSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
             animations: {
                    standRight:[0],
                    standDown:[32],
                    standLeft:[57],
                    standUp:[8],
                    standDiagUpRight:[16],
                    standDiagUpLeft:[24],
                    standDiagDownLeft:[48],
                    standDiagDownRight:[40],
                    walkDiagUpRight:[16,23,"walkDiagUpRight"],
                    walkDiagUpLeft:[24,31,"walkDiagUpLeft"],
                    walkDiagDownRight:[39,46,"walkDiagDownRight"],
                    walkDiagDownLeft:[47,55,"walkDiagDownLeft"],
                    walkRight:[0,7,"walkRight"], 
                    walkLeft:[57,63,"walkLeft"], 
                    walkUp:[8,15,"walkUp"], 
                    walkDown:[32,39,"walkDown"]},
            images: ["img/swordsman-spritesheet.png"],
            frames: {width:96, height:96, regX:48, regY:48 }
        });

        player = new createjs.Sprite(playerSheet);

    }
    gameInit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sprite animation never has the chance to run on the diagonals because you are calling `detectKeys()` on every tick and if the diagonal key combination evaluates to true, it starts the animation over. You have the right idea in your regular walk animations by first checking to see if your player is already walking before the gotoAndPlay like so:

```
if (keysPressed[38] === 1) {    
    if (player.currentAnimation !== "walkUp") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkUp"); }
    moveChar(player, 0, -1);
}
```

You need to do this for your diagonals as well. Something like:

```
if (keysPressed[38] === 1 && keysPressed[37] === 1) {
    if(player.currentAnimation !== "walkDiagUpLeft") { player.gotoAndPlay("walkDiagUpLeft"); }
}
```